# I tried to run someone else's project in xcode and I got a "Build Failed"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, build

When I go to the window "Build Results", I see an error. The error says "There is no SDK with the name or path '[PATH NAME]'"

Answer (score 2):

Go into Xcode click 'Project' at top and then 'Project Settings' Click the 'Build' tab and then make sure the 'Base SDK' is the latest one.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely they built it with an earlier version of the sdk.

1. Double click the project name to
   bring up the project settings.
2. Go to the Build Tab
3. Set Base SDK to Latest
   iOS

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, but I still think this should stay up for the benefit of others.

In xcode I looked at the menu bar and go to Window > "*.xcodeproj". The '*' is the name of your project.

When you look at the Project window for xcode look for a blue circle with an italicized lower case "i". Click on it. A Project info box should pop up. navigate to the "Build" tab. There is a table with two columns: Setting and Value. Look under the "Setting" column for "Architectures" > "Base SDK". Click the Cell under the "Value" column that corresponds to the "Base SDK" row. A table should pop up and I clicked on "Latest iOS..." Return to the xcode project window and click the button with the hammer and the green orb to Build and Run using the new path.